# Imperfekt vs Perfekt

Tags: meaning, difference, conjugation

My question is about the difference between these two sentences:

> Der Hund lief neben der Herde mit. (Imperfekt)

vs

> Der Hund ist neben der Herde mitgelaufen. (Perfekt)

I think both sentences are grammatically correct, but where's the difference? When do you use one, but not the other?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Beta and RHa pointing out the correct namings for both forms, I was able to find the answer myself.

Similar to the English versions, it seems Imperfekt is used when something *started and ended* in the past, while with Perfekt something started in the past and has some sort of *impact on the present* (also may or may not have ended in the present).

Comment: Yes, this is true for written German. However in spoken, and particularly colloquial German you use the imperfect very little, but for a few verbs such as "sein" and "werden". I.e the perfect here replaces imperfect.

Comment: Although my question is actually geared towards written German, I got confused since both versions spoken aloud seem very familiar ("normal"). Maybe it's regional, but I really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

> Der Hund ist neben der Herde mitgelaufen

is *Perfekt* which consists of Partizip 2 and the indicative present of *Haben* or *Sein*, depending on the main verb. In the case of *mitlaufen*, it's *Sein* which here becomes *ist*.

Perfekt is used when something happened in the past and is usually preferred over the preterite in spoken language.

Partizip 2 cannot be used alone as a verb in a sentence because it is not a finite verb form. If you see it without an auxillary verb there is an implied auxillary which has been omitted.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the correct naming. With this I was finally able to google the differences between the two.